# Azure pipline Log adding message form C# in a run task

Tags: c#, logging, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-pipelines-tasks

I would like to know if it is possible to log a message from C# code in the [azure pipeline log window (below) while using a run task. I need to print some variables that I can only get if my functions are executed in Azure in order to debug.

[image]

Comment: _"typo"_ - no need to comment as you can always [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63786072/edit) your question by clicking **edit** above

Comment: @MickyD I have checked it out before posting my question. This is logging from the yml file. I want to do it from C# code if possible!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use `System.Console.WriteLine` and you will get it printed in logs.

Comment: Works like a Charm! btw @MickyD, this is not a duplicate of what you have linked. I wanted to do this from C# code.